# firebase-admin admin.database() makes infinite loop without returning anything

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

Hi im new to firebase and in my first test i followed the documentation of how to retrieve data from a realtime database i configured the rules for accessing + writing the code also generated the key which is needed for firebase-admin SDK 
and here is the code

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./generatedPrivateKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
 credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
 databaseURL: "https://alan-b6de4.firebaseio.com/"
});


var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("users");
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
 console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

every thing looks fine this ,the problem is that when i run this code it loops without returning anything the console screen just holds but when i take the same code without any modification to another computer it works just fine :(

I use latest stable version of nodeJs which is 8.9.4

Comment: `var ref  = db.ref().child("users");` instead of `var ref = db.ref("users");`

Comment: nope it did not solve the problem , the  code in my question works fine just in my computer it waits without displaying anything

Comment: This is usually a sign of an authorization/credentials problem. Try enabling debug logs and see what turns up: `admin.database.enableLogging(true)`